# What is the purpose of this thing on NiMH rechargeable batteries ? Can't figure out what this component is or its purpose

Tags: batteries, component-selection, nimh

[image: Red circle]

What is the purpose of this thing on NiMH rechargeable batteries? I can't figure out what this component is or what it is for.

I'm trying to change the batteries in a Hoover automated vacuum cleaner.

I want to know if it is necessary to have these on the new set of rechargeable NiMh batteries.

Comment: Are you asking what the connector is for? Because from the photo it just looks like a connector to me. But I have to assume you wouldn't be asking what a connector is for.

Comment: It appears to be a crimp connector.  You put the wires in it and crimp it.

Comment: The page in the background is nicely in focus. The blurry thing in the foreground could be a fuse. Draw the circuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a thermal protector. This is likely a self-resetting bimetal type, unlike the cylindrical type that has a low melting point metal inside with a spring- they open once and then have to be replaced.

Here is a typical product (photo from [Alibaba](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/17AM034A5-135c-thermal-protector_60652002600.html)):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thermal protection.

A sane battery is expected to have one for fire safety.

May be either a fuse (single-use) or a bimetal disconnector (reversible - reconnects the circuit once cooled).

Most of these have a temperature written on them.